# Custom button on custom tab is always disabled (ribbon bar)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I found a lot of examples how to add custom tab with custom controls on the ribbon bar. But no one works for me. I got the custom tab, but button is always disabled.
There is my current version of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="CustomRibbonTab"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationId="101"
    RegistrationType="List">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
          <Tab
            Id="Ribbon.CustomTab"
            Title="Custom Tab"
            Description="Custom Tab !!!"
            Sequence="701">
            <Scaling
              Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Scaling">
              <MaxSize
                Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.MaxSize"
                GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup"
                Size="OneLargeTwoMedium"/>
              <Scale
                Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Scaling.CustomTabScaling"
                GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup"
                Size="OneLargeTwoMedium" />
            </Scaling>
            <Groups Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Groups">
              <Group
                Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup"
                Description="Custom Group!"
                Title="Custom Group"
                Sequence="62"
                Template="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
                <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup.Controls">
                  <Button
                    Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup.CustomButton"
                    Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
                    Sequence="115"
                    Description=""
                    LabelText="Custom Button"
                    Image32by32="/_layouts/images/PPEOPLE.GIF"
                    TemplateAlias="cust1"/>
                </Controls>
              </Group>
            </Groups>
          </Tab>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
          <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
            <Layout
              Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
              LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
              <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
                <Row>
                  <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust1" />
                </Row>
              </Section>
            </Layout>
          </GroupTemplate>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
           CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello, world!');"
          EnabledScript="javascript:return true;"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

I cleaned up the cache. I read about importance of EnabledScripts attribute in the CommandUIHandler. But I always have the same result:

[image: Disabled button]

Did anybody have the same issue? Please help!

Comment: I have the same problem is SP2013. Was you able to solve it?

Comment: @vk_muse, try to clean cache and do hard reload. It helped me as far as I remember.

Answer (score 3):

I checked out a local custom action of mine, and the EnabledScript followed a different pattern:

```
EnabledScript="javascript:function JustReturnTrue()
{
      return true
}
JustReturnTrue();"
```

If your item is showing up, but always disabled, I bet that's where the problem is.

I think the attribute is optional anyway, if I recall.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I'm not sure if this is the proper solution, I'm a newbie. I removed the element from feature which scope was set to "Site", added another feature, set the scope to "Web", added my button item in this feature, saved, deployed, enabled the new feature from site features and it worked.